# How to make external microphone default?

Tags: alsa, microphone

My laptop's internal microphone is broken and I use only the external one.

However, each time I switch the computer on, I have to change it from internal to external in command-line `alsamixer` or `alsamixergui`, gnome alsa mixer and Preferences → Sound don't show the int/ext switch.

How can I change it permanently?